# I'm a student and I can't run program in C (visual studio), when I include a library like stdio.h

Tags: c, stdio, linkage

I'm in class where we're learning C, and a few weeks ago I noticed whenever I included any library with `#include<stdio.h>` an error takes place.

For this simple piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <locale.h>

int main() { 
    printf("Hi"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)   P2ficha4    E:\Programacao1\P2\P2ficha4\P2ficha4\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)  1
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  P2ficha4    E:\Programacao1\P2\P2ficha4\Debug\P2ficha4.exe  1
```

This has been a really big set back for me, and I don't think my professor can help me on this one. I appreciate any help

Comment: Add a sample code, and describe how you compile it.

Comment: Do you *have* a `main` function?

Comment: Yes, I knew how to code before uni. I've looked at the documentation for the error but it doesn't seem very helpful

Comment: Grep everything for 'P2ficha4'

Comment: What do you mean Martin? Nor familiar with the term grep

Comment: Here's the code I'm trying to run @anastaciu #include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hi");
    return 0;
}

Comment: The file name, including extension?

Comment: @anastaciu The stdio.h is a standard C library. It comes with visual studio. and I have no idea where to find it

Comment: I mean the file where you have your code.

Comment: What would you recomend me to do with it? Also, it seems like something is breaking the linkage. I created a new project, worked the first time. Pasted the professor's code and it stopped working. Then I tried only doing a printf and still didn't work

Comment: How did you create your project in Visual Studio? What is the project type? And what is the full name (including extension) of ***your*** source file?

Comment: I was thinking the other way arround, so for C if you have a .cpp extension it wouldn't work, but a .cpp file with C code should work, though it shouldn't be used like that.

Comment: I have .c extentions. Also, I figured out what was wrong! But thanks you all for helping me brainstorm. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

My partion of E was disconnected from C by root. I made the project in the same partion (C) that windows was installed, I also selected the "make solution as same directory of project file". It was working for all semester until now, I don't know what triggered it. Thank you all for helping me brain storm